# Pass a std::function as template parameter to another function does not compile

Tags: c++, function, boost, boost-bind

I develop in C+03 using Boost. 
I would like to bind a function class member.  Then pass this to a generic wrapper as template parameter and inside the wrapper to call the real function . But I cannot make this to compile.

Below is a demo code

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Request;
class Request2;
boost::function<int (const char *,const char *, Request     *request)> RequestFunc; 
boost::function<int (const char *,const char *, Request2 *request)>     RequestFunc2;
class Request
{

};
class Request2
{

};
class BindingProxy
{
    public:
    int  sendRequest(char *,char *, Request * request)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
class BindingProxy2
{
    public:
    int  sendRequest(char *,char *, Request2 * request)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
template <typename F>
void wrapperFunc(F func)
{
    Request request;
    func("","",request);
}
int main()
{
  BindingProxy proxy;  

  RequestFunc  = boost::bind(&BindingProxy::sendRequest, &proxy,_1,_2,_3 );

  wrapperFunc(RequestFunc);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, signature of `sendRequest` doesn't match to signature passed into `boost:function`, should be:

```
int  sendRequest(const char *,const char *, Request * request)
```

Second, wrapper takes pointer to request, so get it and pass:

```
Request request;
func("","",&request);
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rKVtwq)